# Why does the value of freed space change so quickly?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, visual-studio-2015

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int* p = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    printf("P = 0x%p\n", p); // prints some address
    p[0] = 0;
    printf("P[0] = %d\n", *p); // prints 0
    free(p);
    printf("P = 0x%p\n", p); // prints same address
    printf("P[0] = %d", *p); // prints -572662307 always
}
```

Why does the value of `*p` change so quickly after freeing up the memory?

I know it's undefined behavior to access and change freed memory. I'm just asking how come that cell always gets garbage written into it every time?

Comment: Reading of freed memory results in _undefined behaviour_ which includes "the freed memory is overwritten by some data".

Comment: "_prints same address_" Why wouldn't it? You didn't change `p`.

Comment: -572662307 is 0xDDDDDDDD. See this answer for other magic values: [In Visual Studio C++, what are the memory allocation representations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)

Comment: But what probably happens here is that the freed memory is overwritten by the special pattern `0xdddddddd` which is facilitates debugging in the case that the freed memory is continued to be used.

Comment: I suspect those magic numbers in memory are a result of a DEBUG build and the debug runtime library. They're probably different in a RELEASE build.

Comment: @Lundin "someone" being `free`, to *very helpfully* show you that dereferencing an invalid pointer has undefined behaviour